# WebRequest doesn't make cached items available in the same process

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest

We're seeing a strange behavior where things that get cached (in the IE/wininet cache) as a result of using the WebRequest API are not available from the cache until a new process is created.

Consider the following code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Cache;
using System.Threading;

namespace HttpCachingTest {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            MakeRequest();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            MakeRequest();
        }

        private static void MakeRequest() {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://a0.twimg.com/a/1286210883/images/twitter_logo_header.png");
            request.CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.Default);

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("IsFromCache: {0}, ContentLength: {1}", response.IsFromCache, response.ContentLength));

            using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite("test.jpg")) {
                response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The behavior we see is that for the second request, IsFromCache is false.  However, if we run the app a second time, then IsFromCache is true.  This implies that things are correctly being cached, but those things that were just cached are not available to the current process, which makes very little sense.

Can anyone explain this behavior, and know how it can be fixed so that cached items can get hit right away?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't disposing of the `HttpWebResponse` nor the stream returned by `GetResponseStream()`. It appears therefore to not have completed processing the request, and the data it obtained can't be safely stored in the cache, as it may not be a full entity. When your process ends, the finalisers will fix this, so it'll be in the cache for the next time it runs.

Dispose up your disposable objects correctly, and the caching behaviour will be as expected.

Comment: Wow, duh!  Feeling like an idiot, bug glad to have a solution :)

Comment: It's not the worse error to make; while it breaks a .NET golden rule, the connection between that and the issue isn't immediately obvious. Indeed, it's quite a good example to use in the future on why one should dispose objects even if it seems from the outside that it should be safe to ignore disposal.